# Using paste and sum inside a for-loop

Tags: r, loops, paste

I need to compare a character string to multiple others and tried to do it the following way:

```
empty = character(0)
ps_2 = c("h2","h3")
ps_3 = c("h3", "h4")
visible = ("h2")

i = 2
ps_t = empty
ps_t <- append(ps_t, sum(visible %in% paste("ps_", i, sep="")))
```

With the intention to write a loop instead of i = 2, in order to cycle trough ps_2,ps_3,...

However I think it's not working since the paste() command returns a string instead of the character string with the name: ps_2.
How can I fix this?

Thanks for the time and effort!

Kind regards,

A fellow datafanatic!

Comment: You can try using `rlang::sym()` which converts a string to a symbol (or object name).

Comment: It returns the following error: " 'match' requires vector arguments "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need is `get()`, which gets the value of the object.

```
ps_t <- ps_t = NULL

sapply(2:3, function(i) append(ps_t, sum(visible %in% get(paste0("ps_", i)))))
```

Or simply:

```
sapply(2:3, function(i) sum(visible %in% get(paste0("ps_", i))))
```

### Output

```
[1] 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` in R to convert the string to a variable name. You can find the solution [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/12/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/).

Here's what your code will look like:

```
ps_t <- c(0, (sum(visible %in% eval(parse(text = paste("ps_", i, sep=""))))))
```

It will give you a numeric vector.

**OR**
You can use `get`.

```
ps_t <- append(0, sum(visible %in% get(paste("ps_", i, sep = ""))))
ps_t
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Maybe I formulated the question unclear. The output I'm looking for is: ps_t = (1,0). Since it has one identical value with ps_2 and 0 with ps_3